# MotionEvent position offsets from finger position

Tags: android, view, imageview

I am just trying to paint a point with canvas.drawPoint where my finger is inside a canvas. Everything works but the problem is that the position retrieved from MotionEvent offsets more and more as my finger moves toward the botton of the screen from my real finger position(the view covers all the screen). Could anybody guess what is happening?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawPoint(upx,upy,paint);
                choosenImageView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawPoint(upx,upy,paint);
                choosenImageView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should never call any Canvas  related methods outside onDraw methid

Comment: Could you comment a bit more about this @pskink?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: thanks. Any tip about the original question though?

Comment: what Canvas are you using?

Comment: I'm using Canvas class. Is this what you are asking?